# Database table prefixes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I don't know if I skipped something in the doc but I don't see the 'tableprefix' statement anymore in the database configuration nor in Models and when I search for tableprefix, I only see it in 2.x documentation.

Is it still possible to use tableprefix and how?

Regards

Comment: "Tables are plural (ArticlesTable), Entities singular and unfortunately still without prefix (Article)" from https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-upgrade/wiki/Upgrading-Notes-for-CakePHP-3.x

Comment: In your table class, use public function initialize(array $config) {
$this->table('prefixed_tablename'); }

Comment: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/4118**

Comment: Thks, I saw that prefixes won't be implemented until 3.1 release. So that's not really a problem except that indexes and foreign keys have long names..

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, as per 3.0. And 3.1 doesn't seem to me that is working on that. So, in the meantime, I think the simplest solution is doing the following:

```
class Post extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = 'wp_posts';

}
```